# How to set background color of item-label in line chart

Tags: jfreechart

I am using **jfree-chart** library to create line chart. 
I want to know how to set background color of **item-label** in line-chart.

Comment: Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: I am not able to find the solution own, that is why I have posted,

Answer (score 1):

Item labels don't even *have* background color, just text. You could try one of the [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) like [`XYTextAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYTextAnnotation.html), which has a `setBackgroundPaint()` method.